# What's the deal with www.domyownpestcontrol.com?

Tags: discussion

We appear to have two users from a website called domyownpestcontrol.com:

- [Michael Hasson](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/11334/michael-hasson)
- [Rico](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/12174/rico)

Both are relatively new to the site.  One has contributed answers that are not related to pest control (12 out of 15 answers are unrelated), and even a [blog post](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2013/03/how-to-build-sturdy-garage-shelves/).  Where he links to his affiliated site, those links are in plain sight, and his user profile clearly describes his affiliation.

The other's posts read more like spam, with links to the site hidden behind other text, and his user profile doesn't describe his affiliation.  At least one of his posts has been deleted with a moderator leaving a comment to declare that affiliation.

So, what should we do about these posts and these users?

Answer (score 4):

In the first instance you could edit out the links if the rest of the answer seems sensible (I've done this).

Next you could consider leaving a comment about the self promotion aspect and ask the user to be careful.

However, if the answer is really just an excuse for posting the link then flag it as spam and it will get dealt with accordingly.

If we get any more we can send a message, suspend or even delete the "spam" account.

The regular user has also been warned about self promotion links in comments, so again if any post appears to be purely there for the links, flag it as spam.

Answer (score 2):

I think you guys are taking this the wrong way. I contributed a blog post (without any links to my website in the post) that took me 4 hours to put together. I have also contributed many answers relating to my background in woodworking, and relating to my current situation with a pest control company. I consider all of my answers helpful, not spam. As for the other user, that could be a phone person that works here as they are advised to go out on the web in their spare time and find threads asking questions relating to pest control that they can answer. Not spam, helpful answers. If you find any questionable answers that are associated with my company, please let me know and I'll put an end to it.

If you have an issue with anything I have written, just let me know, rather than start a thread behind my back that associates my name with spamming. I have nothing to hide and I don't mind changing anything to comply with your rules. I'm trying to help build your network.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Hasson originally emailed the blog, looking for the opportunity to contribute a blog post.  He was given a chance to contribute, after he made an effort to be part of the DIY.SE community. He has been made aware that linking to his site (other than from his user profile), is not alright.  If you notice abuse, please flag it, and it will be dealt with.

Comment: I was never told that providing useful links to my website is prohibited in the threads. I was told to make sure people know of any association I have to linked sites, but that doesn't mean that I can't provide them when applicable. Why would I not, if it makes sense to help answer the question?

Comment: @MichaelHasson That's correct.  If a link to your site helps answer the question, and you've made known your affiliation, then it shouldn't be a problem.  It will only be a problem if you start linking to your site in less than appropriate answers.  As long as you keep it from becoming spammy, there should be no problem. Keep the good answers coming.